How to create a simple page in wordpress with a list of the SKUs and stock of each one?
In a wordpress-woocomerce store I need to create a simple text PHP page (no banners, no headers, no footers) that outputs a list of all the SKUs and the stock of each one, like this.
SKU_A;3
SKU_B;14
SKU_C;44

So it should be the SKU followed by a semicolon followed by the stock of the SKU
Ive tried with chatGPT instructions but it didnt work, or I was doing something wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.
Ive created stock.php file in the root directory (public_html) with this code, and tried accesing it from www.mywebsite.com/stock.php, but I get a "This page has not been found" message.
// Load WordPress environment
require_once('wp-load.php');

// Query to retrieve SKUs and stock quantities from WooCommerce database
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);

// Output SKUs and stock quantities
if ($products->have_posts()) {
    while ($products->have_posts()) {
        $products->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if (!empty($sku) && isset($stock_quantity)) {
            echo $sku . ';' . $stock_quantity . "\n";
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No products found';
}
?>```


What webserver are you using? This looks more like a misconfiguration.

Litespeed. Veerotech hosting

It was the cache of my browser. Silly me.
